# [GNS3]No package metadata was found for gns3-server

Tags: python

After updating the system, gns3 cannot run
Console output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gns3server", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('gns3-server==2.2.27', 'console_scripts', 'gns3server')())
  File "/usr/bin/gns3server", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
    for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 919, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 518, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for gns3-server
```

Error code block in file  /usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/**init**.py

```
def from_name(cls, name):
   504          """Return the Distribution for the given package name.
   505
   506          :param name: The name of the distribution package to search for.
   507          :return: The Distribution instance (or subclass thereof) for the named
   508              package, if found.
   509          :raises PackageNotFoundError: When the named package's distribution
   510              metadata cannot be found.
   511          """
   512          for resolver in cls._discover_resolvers():
   513              dists = resolver(DistributionFinder.Context(name=name))
   514              dist = next(iter(dists), None)
   515              if dist is not None:
   516                  return dist
   517          else:
   518              raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
```

gns3server version 2.2.27
OS:arch
kernel:5.15.7-arch1-1
Python:3.10.0
If you need to know which packages have been upgraded
I can also provide